# What does the Ctrl-Alt-+ shortcut do?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Simple question. I was about to assign the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> keyboard shortcut to increase the volume, but I then realized it was already assigned for something. If I press this key combination the screen flashes black for a second, and then comes back. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> produces similar behavior. So I'm curious, what's this shortcut supposed to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> are mapped for switching between *virtual consoles*. Your graphical display is usually mapped to `vt7` or `vt8`, so <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>BkSp</kbd> aborts your graphical server and kills all graphical processes.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> switch to a smaller or higher screen resolution, respectively.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> runs `xkill` by default. The next window you click is killed.

There are several others, but I can't recall them.

---

If you want to map <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> to something, I'd suggest using the Windows key as a modifier, if you have one. It's treated as a "Super" Meta-key, and doesn't normally have any mappings at all.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE and CTRL+ALT+ESC are disabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: It is probably worthwhile to note that Ctrl-Alt-F1 is caught by the operating system and are best not messed with and Ctrl-Alt-`+` is caught by the XServer which is more configurable, and less critical especially if (like many) you don't switch resolutions.